# Difference when use htmlAttributes

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What's difference between:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Soluongton, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

and

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Soluongton, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" } })
```

and what's `htmlAttributes`?

Comment: Look at the actual html it generates and you will see the 2nd one is wrong.

Comment: `new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" } }` => this is only used in `EditorFor`. `LabelFor` uses the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Soluongton, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

will render the HTML code:

```
<label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Soluongton">Soluongton</label>
```

---

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Soluongton, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" } })
```

will render the HTML code:

```
<label for="Soluongton" htmlAttributes="{ class = control-label col-md-2 }">Soluongton</label>
```

As you can see the second `@Html.LabelFor` will render a wrong HTML output.